# Does apple approve my app consists of only a single web view

Tags: uiwebview, iphone-5

I have build an app which is only one view page app. There is a single web view which shows the content of a web page. There is no any other control in the whole app. If I submit the app in apple store then does apple approve this app or will reject it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because we don't know if your app will be approved

Comment: Hi, I may be late to the party, But felt I should update. Your app will get approved if you have created your web application using some mobile framework like jQuery mobile. Also add some activity indicator, check for network connection etc. I just got an app approved which was built just with webview.

Comment: So have you submitted it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm almost certain they will reject it. If you have a look at the Apple guidelines it states:

> **2.12:** Apps that are not very useful, unique, are simply web sites bundled as Apps, or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may be rejected

I believe your app falls into this group.

Here is the full review guideline: (Must be logged in to your Apple developer account)
https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html#pornography

Comment: No problem. Please accept the answer as correct so it may help others in future.